# How to check specific number of checbox and disable remaining using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

In a specific DIV having `.vipGuests` that have multiple checkboxes (More than 12), I want to select maximum 12 checkboxes. 
As soon as user select 12th checbox then remaining checkbox will get disabled.

My below mentioned code is only counting number of checkbox that are checked. How I can implement the functionality so that user can check maximum 12 checkbox and remaining will get disabled.

```
$('.vipGuests input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {             
    var totalGuest = 0;
    $('.vipGuests input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        totalGuest++;
    });
});
```

**Note**: The main thing is that each time during check/uncheck when counter of Checkboxes that are checked is 11 then all checkbox will be active. Only when counter is equals to 12 then the only unchecked checboxes will get disabled.

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle

Comment: @user2181397 Sorry.Currently I am unable to generate a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.
[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zwhdx26n/)

Code:

```
var totalGuest = 0;
$('div input[type=checkbox]').not(":radio,:submit").on('change', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");

  if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
   totalGuest ++;
 }
 else {
   totalGuest --;
 }

 if(totalGuest >= 12) {
   $('input[type=checkbox]').not(".active").attr("disabled","disabled");
 }
 else {
   $('input[type=checkbox]').not(".active").removeAttr("disabled");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and select un-checked checkbox and disable them. Also you don't need to use `.each()` to get count of checkbox. Use `length` property instead.

```
$(".vipGuests :checkbox").on("change", function(){
    if ($(".vipGuests :checkbox:checked").length >= 3)
        $(".vipGuests :checkbox:not(:checked)").prop("disabled", true);
    else
        $(".vipGuests :checkbox:not(:checked)").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```js
$(".vipGuests :checkbox").on("change", function(){
    $(".vipGuests :checkbox:not(:checked)").prop("disabled", $(".vipGuests :checkbox:checked").length >= 3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vipGuests">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: You should be using `.prop('disabled', true/false)` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rely on `length` of jQuery object to check if 12 items are selected.
Use `:not(:checked)` selector for disabling non-checked inputs.

```js
var $checkboxes = $('.vipGuests input[type=checkbox]');
$checkboxes.on('change', function() {
  if ($checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= 12) {
    $checkboxes.filter(":not(:checked)").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $checkboxes.prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="vipGuests">
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>1 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>2 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>3<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>4 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>5 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>6<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>7 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>8 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>9<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>10 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>11 
  <input type="checkbox" />12<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" />13 
  <input type="checkbox" />14 
  <input type="checkbox" />15
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable as below:

```
     var totalGuest = 0; 
     $(".vipGuests :checkbox").on("change", function(){
       this.checked?totalGuest++:totalGuest--;
       $checkboxes.filter(":not(:checked)").prop("disabled", (totalGuest>=12)?true:false);
       });
```